Cloudflare times out when displaying pages with CSS/JS
Update (8/22/2024): I've tried setting up Nginx to solve this but it also faces the same issue. In addition the people who've replied both here and on Reddit both tell me this is a Cloudflare issue. As such, I'm going to re-explain this problem, from the perspective of it being a Cloudflare problem.
I run a personal website through Apache and Cloudflare. At the end of July, after switching to a new ISP, my dad and brother had no issues, and their website servers (on the same network) required no reconfiguration. However, I faced an issue where accessing my website's domain (which points to the public IP) would time out. After lots of troubleshooting, I was able to determine that the timeouts only occurred when the pages in question contained CSS or JS code. If I removed all CSS and JS (i.e. <style>, <script>, and <link> tags), I could access any page perfectly. I tried switching to Nginx however it didn't help. So, I've determined this is an issue with Cloudflare, but I don't know what exactly to change in Cloudflare in order to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated.
Original post below:

 I run a website using Apache on my own Ubuntu server. I recently switched ISPs, and now my website times out when accessed through its' domain (the local IP for my server works perfectly). I tried switching to hosting a fresh install of Apache through a Docker container, and it does work fine when using a simple test page (i.e. the "It works!" page which comes standard with Apache). However, on either of the Apache instances, any page with a script or style tag will not load at all on my browser (even from an external network). It simply times out. Apache logs don't show anything weird. This would lead me to believe it's an issue with my htaccess or with the configuration of Apache.  TL;DR: Website domain times out if trying to display pages with <script>, <style>, or <link>. Local server IP loads these pages fine. Problem persists on clean Apache install and Apache logs show no errors. Could anyone help? Thanks. EDIT: In order to help diagnose this issue, I'll include some more details below: My setup: My ubuntu server is running on my home network, which underwent an ISP change last week. My website runs on Apache and is tunneled through Cloudflare. Also on the same network is a server running my brother's website, which was unaffected by the ISP change and which also runs Apache. What works: - Accessing my domain with pages containing plain HTML (i.e no JS or CSS).  - Accessing the local IP of my server. Any pages served this way work perfectly.What doesn't work: - Accessing pages from my domain, if such pages contain JS or CSS. - By "an external network", I mean that I've tried using a VPN, mobile data, and even contacting a friend in the USA (just in case it's a local ISP issue), and the domain times out on each of them.Personally, I'm not sure if the issues I'm facing are due to a misconfiguration of Apache, a network firewall (although this seems unlikely), or some issue with Cloudflare, so I can't answer as to what exactly changed in order for this issue to arise.


I assume your Ubuntu server isn't located at the location where you changed the ISP? When you say: "even from an external network", are you using a VPN? I find your question very confusing and cannot work out what's located where, what changed, and what does work and doesn't. Remember, all we have is your question, we cannot see what your situation is and we cannot do any tests ourselves.

Hi, apologies for the confusing wording, I'm new to StackExchange. I'll try to break things down better.
My setup: My ubuntu server is running on my home network, which underwent an ISP change last week. My website runs on Apache and is tunneled through Cloudflare. Also on the same network is a server running my brother's website, which was unaffected by the ISP change and which also runs Apache.
What works: #1: Accessing my domain with pages containing plain HTML (i.e no JS or CSS). #2: Accessing the local IP of my server. Any pages served this way work perfectly.

What doesn't work: #1: Accessing pages from my domain, if such pages contain JS or CSS. #2: By "an external network", I mean that I've tried using a VPN, mobile data, and even contacting a friend in the USA (just in case it's a local ISP issue), and the domain times out on each of them.

Personally, I'm not sure if the issues I'm facing are due to a misconfiguration of Apache, a network firewall (although this seems unlikely), or some issue with Cloudflare, so I can't answer as to what exactly changed in order for this issue to arise.

To me this sounds like a Cloudflare issue, assuming that your brothers website isn't using it, or has a different Cloudflare configuration. The file types, that you say don't work, are typically the type of files Cloudflare would cache. Please edit your question to include the new information you added in your comments. I might not know the exact answer, but other people might, if you ask a clear question. When people read an unclear question they might not take the extra effort to see if the comments can clarify things.

What could also help if you tell us what you see in the network tab of your browser developer tools. Does the page load with an error code? Does the HTML page load, but the linked files don't? Is there an error message in the browser console?

The only request that appears on the network tab is the request to the document. The page itself is prevented from loading. Occasionally the Cloudflare timeout page loads, but not always.

When trying to troubleshoot a few days ago, I managed to get one of my site's pages to load, however the navbar page (which is an iframe) timed out. Looking at the network tab, the images and other resources from that navbar page were requested, but all timed out in the end.

What happens if you change the DNS to point directly to the external IP - ie ruling out Cloudflare?   Relatedly, is it possible the Cloudflare is providing an old/cached version amd there is an issue between Cloudflare and your server?

The domain registration account is owned by my dad and I can't reach him right now, so I don't think I can try that. However, I can try force purging the Cloudflare cache.

Forgot to comment it here, but purging the cache didn't work.
